How to close a view part without saving its state?
We are migrating our RCP application from Eclipse 3.8 to Eclipse 4.
In Eclipse 3.8, the saveState (IMemento) method of views was only called when closing the application, for views that were still open.
In Eclipse 4, when I close a view, without closing the application, the saveState method is also called.
Is there any way to change the behavior of Eclipse 4 to be the same as Eclipse 3.8?
I've already looked for a tag to be added to the views to change this behavior and I couldn't find it.

What's bad about having saveState() called? What's the actual problem here?

Because all my views have default options, which must be used when a new view is opened.
With the options being saved in the view's state and we reusing the view's secondary ID, the way our application is implemented, the default options are not being used as they should.
To avoid changing the way views work, it would be better for us if the state was not saved when closing a view without closing the application.

Looks like the PersistState annotation invocation in org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine does this. There does not appear to be any way to prevent the call. This area of code was completely rewritten for Eclipse 4.

Thanks for your reply. Therefore, I will change my saveState methods so as not to save anything in the memento key if the application is not being closed. It will resolve.

As greg-449 said, there is nothing to prevent Eclipse from saving the state of the view when it is closed.
Therefore, to resolve my situation, in my saveState(IMemento) methods I test whether the application is being closed, if not, I do not save the view settings in the memento key.
To know if the application is being closed, I have an implementation of the IWorkbenchListener interface and it has the preShutdown method. When this method is called I know that the application is being closed.
